# SSRS: Dataset error with odbc datasource

Tags: reporting-services, odbc, datasource

I am trying to create a dataset using a shared datasource.
My datasource is a ODBC connection to Impala.

When I add the datasource in SQL Server Reporting Builder, the connection is successful.
But when I try to add a dataset with this connexion, I get this error:

*ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The name of the data source is not found and no default driver was specified*

This error only happens in remote mode.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have ran into this.  The ODBC connection has to exist on both the server running SSRS and the PC running Report Builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ODBC connection has to exist on the PC client that is using Report Builder.
Thanks [Jesse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5899795/jesse)